# C#. Зависает программа при обработке результата SQL-запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Зависает программа. Ошибок не выдёт.
Только в Diagnostic Tools есть вот такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код обычный, запрос (select) выложить не могу, но в SQL Server Management Studio запрос отрабатывает без ошибок, выводит 37 тыс записей. Из-за количества записей зависает программа? Как решить проблему с зависанием?

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=*;User ID=*;Password=*";
            SqlCommand thisCommandDS = conn.CreateCommand();
            thisCommandDS.CommandText = "";
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader thisReaderDS = thisCommandDS.ExecuteReader();

            string ds = "";

            while (thisReaderDS.Read())
            {
                ds = thisReaderDS["ds"].ToString();
                rTB_ds.Text += ds + " ";
            }
            thisReaderDS.Close();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: а если убрать `rTB_ds.Text += ds + " ";`, лучше?

Comment: да, не зависает.

Comment: но вы уверены, что хотите вывести 37 тысяч записей в текстовое поле? Поле может тормозить под такой гнагрузкой.

Comment: Тогда проблема видимо в rTB_ds, который скорее всего каждый раз пытается перерисовать текст. Попробуйте вариант @tym32167, но чаще всего такие объемы стараются просто не отображать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна из причин - вы пытаетесь склеить 37 тыс трок друг с другом. Попробуйте StringBuilder

```
string ds = "";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (thisReaderDS.Read())
{
    ds = thisReaderDS["ds"].ToString();
    sb.Append(ds);
    sb.Append(" ");     
}   
rTB_ds.Text += sb.ToString();
```